# Creating RPM using Ant on Cygwin

Tags: ant, cygwin, rpm, rpmbuild

So I have a basic Java program I am trying to package as an RPM using Ant's [rpm](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/rpm.html) task.  I am running this through Cygwin.  My problem is when I run the ant build script, it seems to be trying to use the rpm command instead of the needed rpmbuild command.  From what I have read, the ant rpm task should use rpmbuild unless it is not found, in which case it then uses rpm. I know for a fact both are installed properly, as I can manually create RPMs using the command line just fine.  I am not sure if there is something I need to change in the build script or the spec file to get this working, as I am new to this sort of thing.  Or if this is a Cygwin dependency issue?

Proof of rpm and rpmbuild install in Cygwin:

```
$ which rpm
/usr/bin/rpm
```

and

```
$ which rpmbuild
/usr/bin/rpmbuild
```

Here is my build.xml file:

```
<project name="SimpleJavaApp" default="all">

<property name="src"        value="${basedir}/src" />
<property name="output"     value="${basedir}/output" />
<property name="classes"    value="${output}/classes" />
<property name="jars"       value="${output}/jars" />
<property name="build.dir"  value="${basedir}/build"/>

<target name="clean">
    <delete dir="${output}" />
</target>

<target name="compile">
    <mkdir dir="${classes}" />
    <javac srcdir="${src}" destdir="${classes}" />
</target>

<target name="jar">
    <mkdir dir="${jars}" />
    <jar basedir="${classes}" destfile="${jars}/app.jar">
        <manifest>
              <attribute name="Main-Class" value="Main"/>
        </manifest>
    </jar>
</target>

<!-- Create directories -->
<mkdir dir="${build.dir}/BUILD"/>
<mkdir dir="${build.dir}/SOURCES"/>
<mkdir dir="${build.dir}/RPMS/noarch"/>
<mkdir dir="${build.dir}/SPECS"/>

<!-- copy spec files -->
<copy todir="${build.dir}/SPECS" preservelastmodified="true" failonerror="true">
    <fileset dir="${basedir}" includes="*.spec"/>
</copy>

<target name="rpm" description="Compile single binary rpm by spec file">
    <rpm
        specFile="project.spec"
        topDir="build"
        cleanBuildDir="false"
        removeSpec="false"
        removeSource="false"
        command = "ba"
        failOnError="false"
    />
</target>


<target name="all" depends="clean, compile, jar, rpm" />
```

And here is my spec file, pretty simple:

```
Summary:    An RPM Spec example
Name:       Application-Example
Version:    1.0
Release:    1
Group:  Applications/Sample
URL:        http://www.mycompany.com
Packager:   Name <name@name.com>
BuildArch:  noarch

%description
This is a sample SPEC file for the RPM project
demonstrating how to build, package, install(deploy)

%files
```

And finally, here is the output of the ant build (only the rpm portion):

```
rpm:
  [rpm] Building the RPM based on the project.spec file
  [rpm] RPM version 4.1
  [rpm] Copyright (C) 1998-2002 - Red Hat, Inc.
  [rpm] This program may be freely redistributed under the terms of the GNU GPL
  [rpm]
  [rpm] Usage: rpm [-a|--all] [-f|--file] [-g|--group] [-p|--package] [--specfile]
  [rpm]         [--whatrequires] [--whatprovides] [-c|--configfiles] [-d|--docfiles]
  [rpm]         [--dump] [-l|--list] [--queryformat=QUERYFORMAT] [-s|--state]
  [rpm]         [--nomd5] [--nofiles] [--nodeps] [--noscript] [--addsign]
  [rpm]         [-K|--checksig] [--import] [--resign] [--nodigest] [--nosignature]
  [rpm]         [--initdb] [--rebuilddb] [--allfiles] [--allmatches] [--badreloc]
  [rpm]         [-e|--erase <package>+] [--excludedocs] [--excludepath=<path>]
  [rpm]         [--force] [-F|--freshen <packagefile>+] [-h|--hash] [--ignorearch]
  [rpm]         [--ignoreos] [--ignoresize] [-i|--install] [--justdb] [--nodeps]
  [rpm]         [--nomd5] [--noorder] [--nosuggest] [--noscripts] [--notriggers]
  [rpm]         [--oldpackage] [--percent] [--prefix=<dir>] [--relocate=<old>=<new>]
  [rpm]         [--repackage] [--replacefiles] [--replacepkgs] [--test]
  [rpm]         [-U|--upgrade <packagefile>+] [-D|--define 'MACRO EXPR']
  [rpm]         [-E|--eval 'EXPR'] [--macros=<FILE:...>] [--nodigest] [--nosignature]
  [rpm]         [--rcfile=<FILE:...>] [-r|--root ROOT] [--querytags] [--showrc]
  [rpm]         [--quiet] [-v|--verbose] [--version] [-?|--help] [--usage]
  [rpm]         [--scripts] [--setperms] [--setugids] [--conflicts] [--obsoletes]
  [rpm]         [--provides] [--requires] [--info] [--changelog] [--triggers]
  [rpm]         [--last] [--filesbypkg] [--redhatprovides] [--redhatrequires]
  [rpm]         [--buildpolicy=<policy>] [--with=<option>] [--without=<option>]

all:

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 1 second
```

Answer (score 0):

if you'd like to see what is happening in ant run, you should understand the sources of the task you're interested in. Not sure what ant version you have but the latest sources can be seen here: http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/ant/core/trunk/src/main/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/optional/Rpm.java?view=markup

The method of your interest seems to be:

```
 /**
 * Checks whether <code>rpmbuild</code> is on the PATH and returns
 * the absolute path to it - falls back to <code>rpm</code>
 * otherwise.
 *
 * @return the command used to build RPM's
 *
 * @since 1.6
 */
protected String guessRpmBuildCommand() {
    Map/*<String, String>*/ env = Execute.getEnvironmentVariables();
    String path = (String) env.get(PATH1);
    if (path == null) {
        path = (String) env.get(PATH2);
        if (path == null) {
            path = (String) env.get(PATH3);
        }
    }

    if (path != null) {
        Path p = new Path(getProject(), path);
        String[] pElements = p.list();
        for (int i = 0; i < pElements.length; i++) {
            File f = new File(pElements[i],
                              "rpmbuild"
                              + (Os.isFamily("dos") ? ".exe" : ""));
            if (f.canRead()) {
                return f.getAbsolutePath();
            }
        }
    }

    return "rpm";
}
```

the reffered constants are:

```
private static final String PATH1 = "PATH";
private static final String PATH2 = "Path";
private static final String PATH3 = "path";
```

So as you mentioned, it basically just tries to find the `rpmbuild` on your path. If it can't be found it goes for `rpm`.

The thing is, that I don't have cygwin installed (as I'm a linux user), but let me propose, what I'd try.

1. try to run ant with `-verbose` option (as suggested here: http://ant.apache.org/problems.html) and see if it tells you something useful
2. if not, try to download ant sources (of the version you use), import them to your favourite java ide and do the remote debugging to see what's happening. I'd put breakpoint somewhere around line 333 to see if rpmbuild has been found. If you're not sure how to setup remote debugging for ant, see: http://www.vitorrodrigues.com/blog/2009/07/10/debugging-ant-tasks-in-eclipse/

I don't know how executables look in cygwin, but the question is if they have `.exe` extension. And another important question is if `Os.isFamily("dos")` will be evaluated to true in cygwin.

have fun :)